# Import several maven project at once in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ can open several projects in the same window using *File > New > Module from existing sources ...*
[image: Importing module from existing sources]

However this option only allows to import 1 project at once.
I need to import 30+ maven projects, is there a solution to import them all at once ?

Answer (score -1):

IntelliJ IDEA provides a way to import multiple Maven projects at once. To do so, follow these steps:

1. Open IntelliJ IDEA and go to the Welcome screen.
2. Click on the "Import Project" button.
3. Navigate to the directory that contains all the Maven projects you want to import.
4. Select all the projects you want to import and click on the "OK" button.
5. In the next dialog, select the "Import project from external model" option and choose "Maven".
6. Click on the "Next" button and follow the on-screen instructions to complete the import process.
7. Once you have imported the projects, IntelliJ IDEA will create a separate project for each Maven project you imported, and you can work with each project individually.

Comment: I'm using Itellij v2022.2.2.
There is no "Import Project" button on the welcome screen but an "Open Project" button instead. Clicking on it allows to select multiple projects, but there is no next dialog after that (it directly opens only 2 projects from the selection).